# What is the condition attribute on a tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a large project that I'm migrating. What does the condition tag on this li element mean?

```
<ul class="u-tab">
    <li t="sys.RtspAuth" data-for="rtsp" condition>
        <!-- RTSP Authority -->
    </li>
    <li t="net.SSH" data-for="ssh" condition>
        <!-- SSH -->
    </li>
...
```

Comment: As far as I know, nothing. It could've been something used by a script written by whoever wrote it originally.

Answer (score 2):

here it looks that condition attribute is a boolean attribute and someone I think wrote it for a purpose and it means nothing for HTML.
maybe someone uses it in a scripting language like javascript

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out for those curious, it's a translation tag. I should have specified that the program was originally produced in China and those t attributes were used for localization.